# how to post on facebook wall for specific list of users using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on specific group of users on facebook such as (close friends, or family, or college friend...) and I used the code bellow. 
code that I used:

### 1

```
FacebookClient fpost1 = new FacebookClient(access_token);
fpost1.Post("/1234567890/feed", new { message = "test post"});
```

note: access_token is working correctly when I am doing some job before this exception.
      I put my friendlist id instead of 1234567890, that you can get it from graph .../me?fields=friendlists

it did not work and gave me this error "(OAuthException - #2) An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."

### 2

```
FacebookClient fpost1 = new FacebookClient(access_token);
fpost1.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "it is very cold.", to="1234567890"});
```

this one work, but it post to "only me" as target.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST graph.facebook.com
me/feed?message="hello"&privacy={"value": "CUSTOM", "allow": "1234567890"}
```

where the 1234567890 is one of friendlists id

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that what you are doing here...

```
FacebookClient fpost1 = new FacebookClient(access_token);
fpost1.Post("/1234567890/feed", new { message = "test post"});
```

is wrong. Because I believe that `1234567890` is a `user-id`, right? Not a `friendslist-id`. According to the documentation this edge/endpoint signature goes like....

```
/{user-id}/feed
```

where `user-id` is obviously a user id.  The documentation states that...

> Most nodes in the Graph API have edges that can be published to (such as Photos or Posts). All Graph API publishing is done simply with an HTTP POST request to the relevant endpoint with any necesssary parameters included. For example, if you wanted to publish a post on behalf of someone, you would make an HTTP POST request as below:

```
POST graph.facebook.com
  /{user-id}/feed?
    message={message}&
    access_token={access-token}
```

Notice that it says "On Behalf of Someone". My understanding is that you are publishing on behalf of someone and to do that, this someone must have requested an access_token through your application. In other words, if this user hasn't logged in to your app and generated a valid access token you cannot publish on his/her wall

Comment: I use on behalf of me, and I know when I use /{user-id}/feed like /me/feed it works, but I want to post something that just some friends can see. like posting a link and want just close friend to see that. how can I do that?. thank you,

Comment: What is `1234567890`? Is that your user id? Your question suggests that it is the id of your friendslist. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: 1234567890 is friendlist id.